# Java Stream API comparing Strings in an array

Tags: java, string, filter, compare, java-stream

I will be happy if someone can explain why I can not compare String in an array using the Stream API in Java.

I am trying to filter only the pairs when the first word is before the second  lexicographically.

```
String[] input = { "Apple", "Banana" };

    Arrays.stream(input)
            .filter( (a,b)-> a.compareTo(b)< 0 )
```

It seems that Java doesn't understand, that "b" is a String, but why?

Comment: Because streams do not do magic.

Answer (score 6):

`filter` expects a `Predicate<T>` (or to be more exact, `Predicate<? super T>`), where `T` is the type of the `Stream` element (`String` in your case).

`(a,b)-> a.compareTo(b)< 0` cannot be interpreted as a `Predicate<T>`, since the `Predicate`'s `boolean test(T t)` method takes just one argument, not two.

`filter` is applied on each element of a `Stream` separately. There are no pairs in your `Stream`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have more pairs to compare, this could be a help:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] input = {{ "Apple", "Banana" }, 
                            {"Orange", "Apple"}, 
                            {"Banana", "Orange"}};

        Arrays.stream(input)
                   .filter(x -> x[0].compareTo(x[1]) < 0)
                   .forEach(x -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));

    }

}
```

And now the output should look like:

```
[Apple, Banana]
[Banana, Orange]
```

Hope it helps you with your problem.

Comment: On second thought this  might be exactly what he wants.

Comment: yeah it might be misunderstanding... But he wrote about filtering out "pairs", so I thought these pairs are filtered out from something bigger and he only can't handle with the condition inside one pair.
Anyway, it's my very first answer and what you wrote before is a precious tip, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare pairs, you need to "make" the pairs yourself somehow, e.g.

```
IntStream indexes =
    IntStream.range(0, input.length-1)
                // Via i you implicitly have access to the pair
                // (input[i], input[i+1])
        .filter(i -> input[i].compareTo(input[i+1]) < 0);
```

This yields the indexes of elements lexicographically before their following element.

You can do further operations on this stream; but it's not entirely clear what result you expect.